# TypeScript Javascript patterns

Tags: meteor, typescript

I am busy creating a **meteor.d.ts** to support my Typescript developments on the Meteor.js platform.  Current status can be found [here](https://github.com/orefalo/meteorts-libs/blob/master/meteor.d.ts)

With that said, I am having issues abstracting two typical javascript patterns.

The first one **Template.myTemplate.events(eventMap)**, where myTemplate can be dynamically created by the user.

Second, the ability to map **this** to a different interface. Meteor uses the pattern a lot. For instance, when calling Meteor.methods(..methods..), the methods are given access to this.isSimulation() which is not visible anywhere else.

Kind of difficult to explain, so a look at the [meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) may help

Any idea how to declare these two patterns?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I'm not of help as I do not know the answer to this question, but in any case this is a very interesting project! Let us know how you get on.

Comment: TS+Meteor project is already out: https://github.com/orefalo/meteor-typescript-compiler. what's missing in library to access Meteor functions as a typed interface. Follow the link on the question above and you can monitor progress. Sincerely.

Comment: Found a feature request for `this` pattern : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/507

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MyTemplate solution**
Provide two interfaces to the user. One that he can use to add new templates to `Template`. Another to allow him to specify the features of a Template:

```
interface ITemplate{

}
interface ITemplateStatic{
    events:Function;
}

declare var Template:ITemplate; 

// the user's code: 
interface ITemplate{
    myTemplate:ITemplateStatic; 
}
Template.myTemplate.events({});
```

**This solution**
To answer your second question about `this`. The only way to do that is to expose the signatures as an interface. It is then the responsibility of the typescript user to get the proper type if he needs it. There is no way to implicity specify the type of `this` inside a function.

```
declare module meteor{
    interface IMethod{
        // A simple sample 
        isSimulation:boolean; 
    }
}

declare var Meteor;

// the user experience
Meteor.methods({
  foo: function (arg1, arg2) {
    var item:meteor.IMethod = this;  
    console.log(item.isSimulation); // now the signature is enforced
    return "some return value";
  }
});
```

Ofcourse I leave the naming convention up to you :)

Comment: Thanks for answering Basarat, didn't think about #1 this way - and I agree that there is probably no better construct in Typescript at this point. Option 2: Interesting too, though I could get something more elegant. but your suggestions shed lights on the topic. Thank you

Comment: Curious about the this solution. Using a class?

Comment: the point is that the class, doesn't expose methods isSimulation